# Possessive pronoun vs "the" when followed by a restrictive relative pronoun

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, possessive-pronouns

> A: Her sister is a good friend of mine
>
> B: Which one?
>
> A: *The/her* sister who worked here years ago.

Are both, *the*/possessive pronouns correct here?

Comment: Yes, although **the** is much more natural.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would only say 'her sister' if there is only one sister. Otherwise you would say 'the sister' to specify one of multiple. "The sister that worked here."

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both the possessive pronoun and the definite article are correct. But I suggest that instead of 'The/Her'you should use 'The one' as it naturally follows the question.

For instance,

A: Her sister is a good friend of mine.

B: Which one?

A: The one who worked here years ago.